# Python Pillow Lib - Text Placement

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Tis may be a really dumb question but I can't seem to find a solid answer on it. Is the Pillow Text coords based on the center placement of the text itself (center point). As in my project the text does not get placed where I want it to.

I've done a little messing around and not seem to have found an answer.

Comment: as I remember it may use different options to put text. And it may need to use special function to calculate text width and height for font which you use. As I remember long time ago I made some answer which shows how to center text on button with PIL.

Comment: see PIL doc: [Text anchors - Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/text-anchors.html). I think you may need `anchor="mm"` to use center of text.

Comment: Please provide any code and steps that you've tried so far.